# When using require statements in my Smart Contract MM doesnt show the require error

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, metamask, ethers.js

I have the following function within my smart contract

```
function setRewardTokenForShareholder(address RWRD) external {
        require(customRewardsAllowed, "Contract: setRewardTokenForShareholder:: Custom Rewards arent allowed");
        
        // Check to ensure we have enough and also that we can 
        uint256 existingBalance = balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require(existingBalance < thresholdForCustomRewards, "You do not have enough tokens to changce your RWRD");

        require(isContract(RWRD), "Contract: setRewardTokenForShareholder:: Address is a wallet, not a contract.");
        require(RWRD != address(this), "Contract: setRewardTokenForShareholder:: Cannot set reward token as this token due to Router limitations.");
        require(!distributor.isBlacklistedRwrdToken(RWRD), "Contract: setRewardTokenForShareholder:: Reward Token is blacklisted from being used as rewards.");

        distributor.setNewRewardForShareholder(msg.sender, RWRD);
    }
```

What I'm trying to do here is do a bunch of checks on the shareholder to ensure they have enough tokens, the contract they want to set as their custom reward isn't blacklisted and is valid. However, when I fail one of the requirements, MetaMask says "We were not able to estimate gas..." and not the custom `require` error message.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I would much rather the error message I've defined would be used.

Comment: It's a problem of ethers (or whatever package you're using) and not of the smart contract

Comment: ah, ok, well in this case i'm using BSCScan and not within a DAPP. So it's potentially that and not MM?

Comment: MM doesn't have a way to show the message I think. So the job should fall on bscscan. In any case you're not doing anything wrong (I just tested on other contracts and no-one show any message).

Comment: ok cool, TY As it is, i'm working on the Dapp and i'm getting the error i expect. the only issue is what happens if someone wants to use the contract instead and not the dapp? will the txn fail and they wont be charged the 0.4 bnb?

Comment: If the tx fails they still pay a gas fee. It's possible that once failed, bscscan will show the error message on the tx page.